# Mailchimp NodeJS ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm stuck on this error trying to do health check on my mailchimp api config and i keep getting ENOTFOUND error. I removed my actual api key

The config api call

```
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "API-KEY",
  server: "us-17",
});

async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

run();
```

Error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND us-17.api.mailchimp.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'us-17.api.mailchimp.com',
  response: undefined
}
```

Followed the developer documentation line by line but can't get past this error. Any help/info would be great

Tried

The config api call

```
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "API-KEY",
  server: "us-17",
});

async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

run();
```

Expected :

```
{
   "health_status": "Everything's Chimpy!"
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure - `"API-KEY"` is just an example, right? Also, are you sure it's not `us17` and _not_ `us-17`?

Comment: It should be `us17`, not `us-17`.

Comment: @msrumon Yes you are right, omg ‍♂️. Thanks boss

Comment: @Boaz yea i redacted my actual api key, and it was the server prefix typo ‍♂️. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Server Prefix typo.

Should have been "us17" not "us-17"

‍♂️.